# How to remove comma separated string of records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, split, trim

How to remove comma separated string "0000-00-00"

```
  ID      Name   Return Date
   1       A     0000-00-00,2016-02-1,2016-1-15
   2       B     0000-00-00,2016-04-1
   3       c     0000-00-00,2016-04-4
```

Expecting Answer

```
  ID      Name   Return Date
   1       A     2016-02-1,2016-1-15
   2       B     2016-04-1
   3       c     2016-04-4
```

Comment: they're strings. you use standard string operations/functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html And if your DB had been properly normalized, you wouldn't need to ask this question. it'd be a simple `delete .. .where date='0000-00-00'` query.

Comment: `SUBSTRING(\`Return Date\` FROM 11);`

Comment: The real solution here is to NOT store multiple values in a single column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think you have 3 cases: `0000-00-00`string at left, right and middle:

```
+------+------+--------------------------------+
| ID   | Name | Return Date                    |
+------+------+--------------------------------+
|    1 | A    | 0000-00-00,2016-02-1,2016-1-15 |
|    2 | B    | 0000-00-00,2016-04-1           |
|    3 | C    | 0000-00-00,2016-04-4           |
+------+------+--------------------------------+
```

Using the [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) function:

```
SELECT `Return Date`, REPLACE(`Return Date`,'0000-00-00,','') as replaced
FROM YourTable;

+--------------------------------+----------------------+
| Return Date                    | replaced             |
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
| 0000-00-00,2016-02-1,2016-1-15 | 2016-02-1,2016-1-15  |
| 0000-00-00,2016-04-1           | 2016-04-1            |
| 0000-00-00,2016-04-4           | 2016-04-4            |
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
```

**Your update sentence would be:**

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET `Return Date` = REPLACE(`Return Date`,'0000-00-00,','') 
WHERE `Return Date` like '%0000-00-00,%';
```

You must do similar queries for the other cases like `'0000-00-00'` at the middle or right.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try this one to replace value from anywhere other position as:

```
Values may be:
+------------------------------+
0000-00-00,2016-02-1,2016-1-15 
2016-02-1,0000-00-00,2016-1-15 
2016-02-1,2016-1-15,0000-00-00
0000-00-00
+------------------------------+

UPDATE YourTable
SET `Return Date` = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(CONCAT(',',REPLACE(`Return Date`, ',', ',,'), ','),',0000-00-00,', ''), ',,', ',')
    )
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('0000-00-00', `Return Date`)
```

Comment: Great logic here, thanks @bharat!